# File.ReadAllLines method on 2D array

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am about to create a media player app, which will handle multiple playlists with of course, multiple songs. I've created an array of strings for the playlist names, they are stored in a text file. I load them with the `File.ReadAllLines` method like this:

```
1darray = File.ReadAllLines("textfilename.txt");
```

Every playlist has his own ID, I have a variable which stores the number of playlists.
I would like to read the Path of the songs with the same method, but it needs a 2D Array

```
2Darray[playlistID, songID]
```

As with the first method I didn't have to specify each element of the array, I will need now to specify the playlistID, and let the File.ReadAllLines method to fill the songID elements, but it doesn`t work like this:

```
2Darray[playlistID] = File.ReadAllLines("textfilename.txt");
```

it says Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2.

How to deal with it?

Hope you understand my bad english!

Comment: Code is better than words.. show us proper code to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Scan directory for playlist files: [Directory class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then enumerate the found files:

```
foreach (string filename in filenames)
{
    // ...
}
```

Use each `filename` as the playlist ID:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> playlists;
```

Collect each file's lines in the dictionary:

```
playlists.Add(filename, File.ReadAllLines(filename));
```

Get a specific playlist's entry (here, 4th of "dupestep.pl"):

```
playlists["dupestep.pl"][3] // index 3 is the 4th, because it's zero-based
```

From here on you should be able to implement whatever you need.

To abstract the list of playlists you can extract the list of keys to translate indices to filenames and viceversa:

```
playlists.Keys
```

Answer (score 1):

While lots of people have suggested alternative solutions to your problem, nobody has yet explained what the original error means.  What you need to understand is that C# makes a distinction between so-called jagged arrays and multidimensional arrays.

A **jagged array** is essentially an *array of arrays*.  Declaring one looks like this:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[4][];
```

This creates an array with four elements, and each of those four elements can be *any array of `int`, of any size*.  This is why such arrays are called "jagged":  some elements can be bigger than others.  You can imagine it looking something like this:

```
[0, 1]
[5, 3, 2, 1]
[]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2]
```

Note the jagged edge.

In keeping with the declaration, jagged arrays are accessed like this:

```
int[] element = jaggedArray[1];
int   value   = jaggedArray[1][2]; // equivalent to element[2]
```

**Multidimensional arrays** behave differently.  A multidimensional array is declared like this:

```
int[,] multidimArray = new int[4, 4];
```

Unlike a jagged array, multidimensional arrays specify the size of both dimensions.  *All of the elements in such an array are of the same size*.  You can imagine it looking more like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3,
 5, 4, 3, 2,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 9, 8, 7, 4]
```

Multidimensional arrays must also be accessed somewhat differently.  Unlike jagged arrays, which are effectively arrays of arrays, a multidimensional array is treated as a single, cohesive unit.  Doing this:

```
int[] element = multidimArray[3];
```

...doesn't make any sense, because a multidimensional array isn't made up of smaller arrays.  You can only access individual values within the array, and you do so like this:

```
int value = multidimArray[3, 2];
```

Note that you have to specify both indices within a single `[]` operator.  These are the "coordinates" of the value you want, so to speak.

And this is the source of your error.  You had a multidimensional array and you were attempting to access its individual array elements, which doesn't make any sense.  To do what you were originally trying to do, you need to use a jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you can map all playlists with their respective songs with a Dictionary>. Ofcourse this can be done better with classes and relations, however to keep it simple we will use the first example:

```
//get all playlists
string[] playLists = File.ReadAllLines("playLists.txt");

//storage
Dictionary<string, List<string>> playListsToSongsMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

//iterate the readed playlists
foreach (string playlist in playLists)
{
    if (!playListsToSongsMap.ContainsKey(playlist))
    {
        playListsToSongsMap[playlist] = new List<string>();
    }

    //add songs to each playlist
    playListsToSongsMap[playlist].AddRange(File.ReadLines("playListWithsongsPath"));
}

//get all playlits
List<string> allPlayLists = playListsToSongsMap.Keys.ToList();

//get all songs in a playlist
List<string> songsInPlaylist = playListsToSongsMap[allPlayLists[0]];
```